# Shopify is automatically adding quantity adjusters to my cart page, how do I remove them?

Tags: shopify

Shopify is automatically adding some sort of quantity adjusters on my cart page.

I can't find anywhere in the template code that these are getting added.

Anyone know how to remove these up and down arrows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search your template for **input** elements, with the **type** = "number" and some **name** with the word quantity in them. That would be what you change to input type="text" to get rid of the numbers.

Comment: I have tried searching and I can't find anything. It's not some CSS3 attribute right? I want to allow them to change the quantity yes, but I don't want those arrows in my input field for design reasons.

Comment: change the input element from type number to type text.

Comment: Savior! That did it! So I'm assuming some JS somewhere is finding inputs with `type="number"` and adding these arrows? Odd that I can't find anything.

Comment: No.. that is just straight up HTML5. Nothing tricky going on anywhere. Can I get my answer approved then? :) thanks...

Comment: If you update your answer. The real answer seems to be that input type="number" adds the arrows in HTML5. So changing the input to type="text" is the fix.